# logstash filter encode character failed

Tags: ruby, encoding, elasticsearch, logstash

we have a log in GB18030 charset, and we want to encode the log to UTF8 when it's shipped from logstash to elasticsearch. After read the document from logstash website, we found a filter could do this for us. I had never used RUBY before, I copied a logstash filter from logstash website and modified a little.

```
# Call this file 'foo.rb' (in logstash/filters, as above)
require "logstash/filters/base"
require "logstash/namespace"
require "logstash/environment"

class LogStash::Filters::Foo < LogStash::Filters::Base

  # Setting the config_name here is required. This is how you
  # configure this filter from your logstash config.
  #
  # filter {
  #   foo { ... }
  # }
  config_name "foo"
  attr_accessor :logger

  # New plugins should start life at milestone 1.
  milestone 1


  public
  def register
    # nothing to do
  end # def register

  public
  def filter(event)
    # return nothing unless there's an actual filter event
    return unless filter?(event)
    # Replace the event message with our message as configured in the
    # config file.
    a = event["message"].force_encoding("GB18030")
    $stdout.write("\n origin:"+a+"\n")
    $stdout.write("\n encoded:+ a.encode("UTF-8","GB18030")+"\n\n")
    event["message"] = event["message"].encode("UTF-8","GB18030")
    # filter_matched should go in the last line of our successful code
    filter_matched(event)
  end # def filter
end # class LogStash::Filters::Foo
```

Here's the screen output

origin:\xA1\xA2\xD3\xFE]\xCA\xFD\xBE\xDD\xD5\xFD\xD4\xD3\xCA\xFD\xBE\xE2\xBC\xD3
encoded:\xA1\xA2\xD3\xFE]\xCA\xFD\xBE\xDD\xD5\xFD\xD4\xD3\xCA\xFD\xBE\xE2\xBC\xD3

It seems the "encode" function didn't work. I tried encode the string above in RUBY2.1.5 interpreter, it works fine.

Comment: Can't you just use the [plain codec's](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/codecs/plain) charset option to indicate that the log is GB18030?

Comment: I tried codec "line" and "plain" and set "charset" GB18030,but it didn't work  at all. The debug infomation report "Receive an event has a different character set .....utf-8 expected"